# CSS Slider Keyframe Cycle

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i have a slider for my website, but my slider error. error slider on animation image 3, 4, 5 can you help me to repair my slider. this my project

```css
/* ANIMATION */
@-moz-keyframes cycle {
 0%  { top:0px; }
 4%  { top:0px; } 
 16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
 20% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
 21% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 92% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 96% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
 
}
@-moz-keyframes cycletwo {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 16% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 20% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 24% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
 36% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
 40% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 41% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclethree {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 36% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 40% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 44% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
 56% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
 60% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 61% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; } 
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclefour {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 40% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 44% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 56% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 65% { top:0px; opacity:1;  }
 76% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 81% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclefive {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 56% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 60% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 64% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 76% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
 80% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 81% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cyclesix {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 76% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 80% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 84% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 96% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
 100%{ top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}


@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
 0%  { top:0px; }
 4%  { top:0px; }
 16% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
 20% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 21% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 50% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 92% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 96% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 100%{ top:0px; opacity:1; }
 
}
@-webkit-keyframes cycletwo {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 16% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 20% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 24% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
 36% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
 40% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 41% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }  
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclethree {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 36% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 40% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 44% { top:0px; opacity:1; } 
 56% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } 
 60% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; } 
 61% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefour {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 40% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 44% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 56% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 65% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
 76% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 81% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclefive {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 56% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 60% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 64% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 76% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
 80% { top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
 81% { top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
 100%{ top:-325px; opacity:0; z-index:-1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cyclesix {
 0%  { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 76% { top:-325px; opacity:0; }
 80% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 84% { top:0px; opacity:1; }
 96% { top:0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; }
 100%{ top:325px; opacity:0; z-index:0; }
}

/* ANIMATION BAR */
@-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
    0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width:0%; opacity:0; }
    4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width:0%; opacity:0.3; }
   16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width:100%; opacity:0.7; }
   17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width:100%; opacity:0.3; }
   18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width:100%; opacity:0; } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
    0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { width:0%; opacity:0; }
    4%, 24%, 44%, 64%, 84% { width:0%; opacity:0.3; }
   16%, 36%, 56%, 76%, 96% { width:100%; opacity:0.7; }
   17%, 37%, 57%, 77%, 97% { width:100%; opacity:0.3; }
   18%, 38%, 58%, 78%, 98% { width:100%; opacity:0; } 
}



#slider{
 background:#000;
 border:5px solid #eaeaea;
 box-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 margin:40px auto 0;
 overflow:visible;
 width: 300px;
 height: 460px;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 position:absolute;
}
#mask {
 overflow:hidden;
 height:460px;
}
#slider ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:relative;
}
#slider li{
 width:300px;
 height:460px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-325px;
 list-style:none;
}

li.animasi1 {
 -moz-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite; 
 -webkit-animation:cycle 25s linear infinite;  
}
li.animasi2  {
 -moz-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:cycletwo 25s linear infinite;  
}
li.animasi3 {
 -moz-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:cyclethree 25s linear infinite;  
}
li.animasi4 {
 -moz-animation:cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:cyclefour 25s linear infinite;  
}
li.animasi5 {
 -moz-animation:cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:cyclefive 25s linear infinite;  
}
li.animasi6 {
 -moz-animation:cyclesix 25s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:cyclesix 25s linear infinite;  
}

.tooltip{
 background:brown;
 width:260px;
 height:60px;
 position:relative;
 bottom:60px;
 left:-500px;
 -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.tooltip h1 {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:300;
 font-family: "Menu";
 line-height:60px;
 padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
li#satu:hover .tooltip,
li#dua:hover .tooltip,
li#tiga:hover .tooltip,
li#empat:hover .tooltip,
li#lima:hover .tooltip,
li#enam:hover .tooltip{
 left:0px;
}
#slider:hover li,
#slider:hover .progress-bar {
 -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
 -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR */
.progress-bar {
 position:relative;
 top:-5px;
 width:300px; 
 height:5px;
 background:white;
 -moz-animation:fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
 -webkit-animation:fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
          <div id="mask">
    <ul>
     <li id="satu" class="animasi1">
     <a href="#wayang"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/wayang.jpg" alt="wayang"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Wayang</h1> </div></li>

     <li id="dua" class="animasi2">
     <a href="#jwayang"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/jwayang.jpg" alt="jenis wayang"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Jenis Wayang</h1> </div></li>

     <li id="tiga" class="animasi3">
     <a href="#twayang"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/twayang.jpg" alt="tokoh wayang"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Tokoh Wayang</h1> </div></li>

     <li id="empat" class="animasi4">
     <a href="#vwayang"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/vwayang.jpg" alt="Video wayang"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Video Wayang</h1> </div></li>

     <li id="lima" class="animasi5">
     <a href="#swayang"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/swayang.jpg" alt="Soal latihan"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Soal Latihan</h1> </div></li>
                    
                    <li id="enam" class="animasi6">
     <a href="#kontak"><img src="http://wayang.16mb.com/gambar/kontak.jpg" alt="kontak"/> </a><div class="tooltip"> <h1>Kontak</h1> </div></li>
    </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="progress-bar">           </div>
    </div>
```

Or you can see there https://jsfiddle.net/JonoRecher/o0a8ezj9/

Comment: I can see no error... what browsers have you tested? Maybe you have a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: This is some hardcore CSS slider I've never seen before. On first glance, I can see that the timing is somewhat off. You have to understand how it works.

Comment: thanks for your comment, if you can see animation image 3 to image 4 to fast not like animation image 1 to image 2. can you repair my css, value property on @-moz-keyframes cyclethree {} and @-moz-keyframes cyclefour{}.

Comment: Please look here: https://jsfiddle.net/dkrvl2011/o0a8ezj9/9/

     Have some issue on start animation - so working on it.....

Comment: Draval, thanks for help to repair my slide. it's working